# CakePHP: findById returning incorrect row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

PHP version: 5.2.17

CakePHP version: 1.3.11

MySQL version: 5.5.9

I'm working on a very simple internal message board website for a client. Since it's for internal use only, the client requested that rather than having usernames and passwords, there is just a password. No usernames. There is one password for the administrator and another password for everybody else.

Here is the database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `regards` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `memo` text,
  `deleted` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;

CREATE TABLE `passwords` (
  `id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `is_admin_password` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

This is my "User" model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $useTable = 'passwords';
}
```

I'm working on the "Change Password" portion of the website now, which is only accessible to the administrator. The form has a dropdown menu where they choose which password they're changing and then they have to type in the current password, new password, and confirm the new password.

Once the administrator submits the "Change Password" form, the controller checks which password they are changing and then looks up that password in the database to verify that they typed in the correct current password. This is the code that looks up the password:

```
$this->User->findById($this->data['User']['id'])
```

For some reason, this is the SQL generated by CakePHP **no matter what the `$this->data['User']['id']` variable is set to (as long as it's a string)**:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`is_admin_password` FROM `passwords` AS `User`   WHERE `User`.`id` = 1    LIMIT 1
```

Why is it always looking up ID 1 even when I tell it to look up ID 2? I've also tried changing the "findById" to a regular "find" and that didn't change anything. It seems to only be when I use the "id" field as the condition. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the value of `$this->data['User']['id']` before the call to `findById()`? Does CakePHP fetch the right record if you hard-code the ID `$this->User->findById(2)`?

Comment: I've echoed it out RIGHT before the findById call and it is 2. I've tried hardcoding "2" as well both as a string and an integer and it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passwords table has its id field defined as tinyint(1) i.e. it can only ever be 0 or 1. CakePHP is doing the right thing.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out and tried to answer my own question, but Stack Overflow said I had to wait another three hours. I figured it out through my own experimenting because I saw no official documentation on the subject. After I figured it out, I found [this page](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/10/06/cakephp-mysql-tinyint1-confusion/). I think it should be better documented.

Also, to clarify your statement for others, "it can only ever be 0 or 1" should probably say "it can only ever be 0 or 1 as far as CakePHP is concerned".

My fix was to change the length of the field to 2.

Answer (score 1):

A bit off topic, but what would happen if one day your client asks you to have a third type of role, meaning not administrator and not what you call today 'everyone else' ? With your database structure it would be difficult to do that.

Personaly I would start with a standard users datatable (i.e. with a username), and well, ok, if you are asked to never display it, well, never display it in the view, but this would be really much more evolutive because the database would be ready for more functionnalities.

And by the way, the fact that you called the model for the 'passwords' datatable 'User' makes me think that your are not far from thinking the same ;-)

Just my two cents...

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're saying. I figure that if I'm ever asked to change it, there will be lots of other things to change as well, like the "from" and "to" fields would have to be "int"s that correlate with the "users" table and I'd have to modify the controller and view for that. Since I'd have to make changes anyway, I'm OK with the way it is right now. But it's good to get another developer's opinion on the subject, so thank you